# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Rails modify passenger config gzip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hi I have an EBS app and trying to enable gzip on this. However when i test for gzip compression, I see that the home page itself is gzip enabled, however the api calls are not gzip enabled.
For example:
masterpiecesart.com - gzip on!
http://masterpiecesart.com/api/v2/countries.json - gzip off!
Do i have to add some additional config files in the .ebextensions folder to enable gzip on all calls?

If so, where should this config be added. In one suggested answer([Increasing client_max_body_size in Nginx conf on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908426/increasing-client-max-body-size-in-nginx-conf-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk/18951706#18951706)), I see that the below /etc/nginx/.. folder is where the conf should be added.

`files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
     mode: "000777"
     owner: ec2-user
     owner: ec2-user
     content: |
     client_max_body_size 20M;
     gzip on;`

However, when I ssh into my ebs ec2 instance, I see no nginx folder inside the /etc/ directory. The nginx server is running at /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.6.2-1002/nginx-1.2.3/sbin/nginx and thr config seems to be from the /tmp/passenger-standalone.1661/config file.

In the config file which I should add to .ebextensions, where should I add the proxy.conf file if not at the "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" as specified in the above answer.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance!

Comment: what exactly are you asking here?