# How to add edit the Elastic Beanstalk ngnix configuration for Ktor Application?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-reverse-proxy, ktor

I ma getting `403 request entity too large` when I try to upload a file of more than 1 mb on elastic beanstalk.

I tried to add my configuration in the `.platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf` file. here is the file content

`client_max_body_size 200M;`

I followed the advice [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) to configure the nginx reverse proxy to allow files larger than the default 1MB.

I tried to create a `.config` file in the `.ebextenstions`. file content look like this

`files: "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" : mode: "000755" owner: root group: root content: | client_max_body_size 200M; commands: 01_reload_nginx: command: "service nginx reload"`

Also tried everything mentioned on this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333676/how-to-extend-nginx-config-in-elastic-beanstalk-amazon-linux-2)

I tried to access the Ec2 instance via terminal and manually add `client_max_body_size 200M;` in the `etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file. this worked but the problem is whenever we deploy the new version on beanstalk this will update the nginx configuration and have to follow the same instructions again after every deployment as Beanstalk also warn the same thing.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTARH.png)

Comment: What is the eb platform version that you are using?

Comment: @Marcin using this doc to deploy the ktor app [here](https://ktor.io/docs/elastic-beanstalk.html)

Comment: @Marcin please reply , I am stuck here since so long.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe ask those who wrote the tutorial. Could be inaccurate.

Comment: I've commented on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-5531.