# How to resolve error 413 Request Entity Too Large in Nginx and Amazon ElasticBeanstalk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have problems upload large images in my project, my configuration is with puma and RoR. My user in the elasticbeanstalk is ec2-user.

I've tried with many configurations that I saw, but it can't works properly. the file in the .ebextensions is like this one:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
    mode: "000777"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        client_max_body_size 4G;
```

Other configuration but it doesn't work

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    content: |
        client_max_body_size 50M;
```

The file is created but without a successful. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increasing client\_max\_body\_size in Nginx conf on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908426/increasing-client-max-body-size-in-nginx-conf-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've already resolved my problem, I had to add: client_max_body_size in the http

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        http {
          client_max_body_size 20M;
        }
```

Comment: Did you need to restart nginx? and if so, how did you do that?

Comment: you need  to do a deploy again, you can do that with the command line: eb deploy

Comment: No need to deploy again as it might not work on the new instances that it will attach while heavy traffic.

Use the other answer by thanhquang1988

Answer (score 4):

I've already slove that with this file :.ebextensions/01_files.config

```
container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "service nginx reload"
files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf":
      mode: "000755"
      owner: root
      group: root
      content: |
        client_max_body_size 0;
```