# Change file size limit on Elastic Beanstalk with Ruby 2.0, Rails 4.1, nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to up the current (2MB) limit on Elastic Beanstalk.

So far, I have:

in a new file, `root/.ebextensions/nginx.conf`

`files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf":
      mode: "000755"
      owner: root
      group: root
      content: |
        http {
          client_max_body_size 50M;
        }`

I haven't had much luck trying to get this to work - any ideas?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908426/increasing-client-max-body-size-in-nginx-conf-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this answer here is correct: [Increasing client_max_body_size in Nginx conf on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908426/increasing-client-max-body-size-in-nginx-conf-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk)

Watch your file extension too, I derped and wrote `.conf` instead of `.config`. Easy enough to do when you use `conf` so much for nginx stuff.

Comment: "Watch your file extension too" - good call, just caught me out.