# 413 request entity too large nginx 1.4.6

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

have tried adding client_max_body_size 200M; inside all the context http, server and location but still users are unable to upload a file of size 30 MB and receive the above 413 request entity error.is there something i'm missing?

Comment: Have you "reload" Nginx?

Comment: reloaded and restarted but still no use.is there a bug or something like that in the version 1.4.6? .

Comment: The nginx serves as the front-end reverse proxy and behind is the tomcat server that house confluence

Comment: I thank all,  the issue is resolved. I need to make a similar update in the backend Nginx server that runs in the same tomcat server serving for ssl encryption as configuring tomcat for ssl is somewhat cumbersome.

Comment: @novice can you explain please how did you solve the problem?

Comment: @Aboozar, we have two nGinx running, one serves as the reverse proxy front end and the other nGinx is actually running inside the application vm serving for ssl encryption so i need to make changes at both nGinx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61943622/7532917 Does this solve your problem