# Spring Boot + Elastic Beanstalk .ebextensions in JAR

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a very standard Spring Boot application (with a `application.properties` properties file located in standard `/src/main/resources` folder) which I'm deploying on AWS Elastic Beanstalk as a "fat JAR".  It works quite nicely but there is an issue with image uploading on the server.  After some investigation it seems that the NGINX configuration needs to be tweaked (increase `client_max_body_size` to something so it can accept uploads up to `10MB`) and therefore I have added an `.ebextensions` folder under `/src/main/resources` with a file with the following content (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908426/increasing-client-max-body-size-in-nginx-conf-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk)): -

```
files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
           client_max_body_size 20M;
```

However, when I run `mvn` on my build it doesn't create `.ebextensions` in the root folder and I'm wondering what is the best solution for this.  My `pom.xml` file is pretty minimal and currently contains the following:

```
    ...

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    ....

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

        </plugin>
```

Thanks in advance!

---

### Update 1

@Lorena when I insert `<resources> ...` XML into my `pom.xml` and then start the server it crashes out with the following: -

```
2017-03-20 21:40:29.504  WARN 10784 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'emailApiSpringBootMail': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'javaMailSender'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2017-03-20 21:40:29.507  INFO 10784 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-03-20 21:40:29.533  WARN 10784 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available)
2017-03-20 21:40:29.637 ERROR 10784 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field javaMailSender in com.myapp.server.api.impl.EmailApiSpringBootMail required a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'mailSender' not loaded because AnyNestedCondition 0 matched 2 did not; NestedCondition on MailSenderAutoConfiguration.MailSenderCondition.JndiNameProperty @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.mail.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'; NestedCondition on MailSenderAutoConfiguration.MailSenderCondition.HostProperty @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.mail.host) did not find property 'host'
```

Removing the XML again fixes the issue so unfortunately this won't work.

---

### Update 2

The issues described in the previous section seemed to be that the new `<resources>` pointing to the `.ebextentions` was overridding  the `<resources>` block defined in: -

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

To get everything working I copied it across and appended to the end as follows: -

```
    <resources>

        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/ebextensions</directory>
            <targetPath>.ebextensions</targetPath>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>

        <!-- Followed is copied from `spring-boot-starter-parent.pom` -->

        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/application*.yml</include>
                <include>**/application*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/application*.yml</exclude>
                <exclude>**/application*.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>

    </resources>
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Have you tried telling it in the pom that it should move the folder to the root?   [Like this](http://codingexplained.com/coding/java/moving-ebextensions-root-war-file)

Comment: That is for deploying as WAR - I'm deploying as a fat JAR so it's easy to run from command line.

Comment: Instead of copying the `<resources>` section you can use the Build Helper Maven Plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64911750/283136

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution proposed by Lorena Salamanca [Spring Boot + Elastic Beanstalk .ebextensions in JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42861558/spring-boot-elastic-beanstalk-ebextensions-in-jar#answer-42909825) not works for me... :\

My solution works with Spring 1.5.3.RELEASE

Add .ebextensions in the root of your project and add this snippet at the end in the plugins section:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <unzip src="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar" dest="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}" />
                            <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/" overwrite="false">
                                <fileset dir="./" includes=".ebextensions/**"/>
                            </copy>
                            <!-- <jar jarfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar" basedir="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}"/>-->
                            <zip compress="false" destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar" basedir="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}"/>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This plugin use ant to unzip the final jar generated by spring boot, copy the .ebextensions in the root and zip (jar) again with the same name. Tested and working in production :)

Comment: Have you tested this across older versions too?

Comment: This worked for me to. The other solution seems a bit less hacky but I cannot get it to work. Thanks for the code @Javier Arnáiz

Comment: Spoke too fast. It's giving me  [Tomcat-startStop-1] ERROR on.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase - A child container failed during start :(

Comment: I tested this on Spring boot 2.0.0 release version and it is working. Also the solution you mentioned also didn't work for me as it is not coping .elasticbeanstalk folder in root of the jar file.

Comment: This technique is also confirmed to work with Spring Boot 2.1.2, maven 3.6, and the current AWS Elastic Beanstalk (Feb 2019).

Comment: @Bampfer I'm trying this solution but when I do deploy, I've an error from nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "files:" in /var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:7. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @drenda The files directive is supposed to be sent to Beanstalk, telling it to create a file called proxy.conf with the `client_max_body_size` directive in it. From your error it sounds like the "files:" command ended up inside the proxy.conf file instead. My guess would be you put the 'files' command in the folder `.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d` rather than `.ebextensions`. (See top-rated answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908426/increasing-client-max-body-size-in-nginx-conf-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk - either method can work but don't mix them.) Hope that helps

Comment: @Bampfer Thank you so much! I finally solved this problem that were annoying me from long time!

Answer (score 7):

Here is a pom snippet that'll make it work for a JAR:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/ebextensions</directory>
            <targetPath>.ebextensions</targetPath>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
        <!-- Followed is copied from `spring-boot-starter-parent.pom` -->
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/application*.yml</include>
                <include>**/application*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/application*.yml</exclude>
                <exclude>**/application*.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

It just works in the same way as [moving .ebextensions to root in .war file](http://codingexplained.com/coding/java/moving-ebextensions-root-war-file)

Actually I uploaded the sample to this [repo](https://github.com/imTachu/moving-ebextensions-jar). Just do a `mvn package`

Comment: Thanks Lorena for you answer.  However, when I added this it the server would not start - question updated.

Comment: Ok, this looks like it is also filtering your properties. This approach that I show you is a solution that you might need to adjust to your specific situation. (since I don't have the entire context of your application) please, do as mentioned [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/749) and let me know.

Comment: As mentioned above - this is very much a standard spring boot application with application.properties in the `/src/main/resources folder`

Comment: Adding `<resource><directory>src/main/resources</directory><filtering>true</filtering></resource>` to your solution fixed my issue.

Comment: Thank you for providing this answer, however I'm wondering why the 2nd and 3rd `resource` children are required for this? It seems to me that omitting those yields the same result. Am I missing something?

Comment: For me this works with `spring-boot-starter-parent` at version `1.3.0.RELEASE`, but not with `1.4.6.RELEASE`

Comment: @johanvas - that's interesting - did you get this to work?

Comment: I tried with Spring Boot 2.0.3 and it seems not to work. Some hint? Could you show how the stucture of the final .jar looks like? Thanks

Comment: this moves the .ebextension folder in the root of the original jar, not the uber jar created by the plugin, right?

Answer (score 4):

I believe in this case that standalone JAR is used, it's easier to go with [Procfile-based configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-procfile.html) and then bundle your JAR and `.ebextensions` into a zip file.

First create a file, called `Procfile` in the root of the project with following content:

```
web: java -jar sample_app-1.0.0.jar
```

Then create a zip file, containing the JAR and `Procfile` file and `.ebextensions` directory:

```
sample_app.zip
|
|_.ebextensions
|   |_ nginx
|      |_ conf.d
|         |_ proxy.conf
|
|_ sample_app-1.0.0.jar
|_ Procfile
```

Comment: What should be the conents of proxy.conf file ?

Comment: @SaurabhPadwekar The nginx configs that you'd like to overwrite. For example something like `client_max_body_size 150M;` would increase the default client max body value.

Comment: Thank you. I followed your suggestion and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you get is for javaMailSender property not found.

The resources path mentioned in your pom.xml overrides the default resources root path.

Hence JavaMailSender is looking for the jndi configuration or the mail properties under this new resources path and its not able to find it.. Hence the error.

```
spring.mail.jndi-name=mail/testmail
```

OR

```
spring.mail.host=testserver.com
spring.mail.port=25
spring.mail.username=test
spring.mail.password=test123
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.defaultEncoding=UTF-8
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms=NTLM
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth.ntlm.domain=DOMAIN
spring.mail.properties.mail.debug=true
```

Comment: I have all these properties in my `application.properties` though and email all works nicely until I added the `<resources>` tag.

Comment: yes. but according to me the javamailsender looks for the same configuration in the new resources path added by you in the pom.xml.. Can you provide the default resources path itself in the pom.xml and check if the issue persists ..

Comment: This is very much a standard spring boot application with `application.properties` in the `/src/main/resources` folder

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is spring-boot jar related issue. As you are using 1.2.6 version of spring-boot, which has some bugs like javamailsender issue. You need to upgrade your spring boot version more than 1.3.0.release.

In this [ticket#3478](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3478), the mailsender issue is fixed for spring-boot. 
So you can upgrade to latest version or others more than 1.3.0 release.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this will solve your issue.