# How to configure SSL for a single instance environment in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to configure SSL for my Spring Boot based application, deployed on Elastic Beanstalk environment. I have followed the AWS documentation by adding conf files under .platform folder.
However after deployment when I try to access my application, I get the default NGNIX page, and somehow the proxy mapping to my Spring Boot application does not seems to work as I'm getting error page. I have verified the conf by logging in to EC2 instance and it seems to be all correct.
If I try to access via https I get connection refused.

**HHTPS Conf file**

[image]

**Conf Structure**

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you verifiy if your certificates are added properly to the instance?

Comment: I did ssh to beanstalk instance and could see both the certs under this directory
/etc/pki/tls/certs

Comment: how are you creating you maven build and uploading it?

Comment: I mean the commands to create the build

Comment: I was uploading the zip. I found the issue, somehow my nginx was not restarting, once I restarted it manually it worked fine.

Comment: You should add the container command to restart server on each upload inside https-instace.config file.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was with `server_name localhost;` in NGINX conf file.  Once I replaced `localhost` with my `sub.domain.com` for which I generated my certificate, the HTTPS traffic started to flow.

So all in all, my procedure was as follows:

- follow the AWS docs for the single instance HTTPS setup ([Terminating HTTPS on EC2 instances running Java SE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-java.html)), making sure to put nginx configs in `.platform` and the rest in `.ebextensions` (search for the differences between Amazon Linux 1 and 2 and pay attention to the paths).
- once again, adjust NGINX SSL config to have your desired domain as `server_name` (see above)
- check in AWS VPC panel that the Elastic Beanstalk security group allows the traffic to port 443 (you can either have `.ebextensions/https-instance-single.config` provision the inbound rule automatically for you as described in the docs or do it manually)