# Maximum request length exceeded in ElasticBeanStalk AWS

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running into Maximum request length exceeded when i upload images into my application which is deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I was wonder how do i configure it to be able to accept larger image size in.

I am using ASP.NET in elastic Beanstalk and using AWS free tier. t2.micro for Elastic Beanstalk environment setup.

Comment: @seb how do it do it? i cant run the RDS upon downloading it.

Comment: Actually my bad I gave a wrong info. Modifying the instance is a bad practice! If it's a IIS limitations (check Jitendra answer first), then I guess you will have to change the web.config you deploy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded

Answer (score 1):

The elastic beanstalk  has the nginx as proxy for your application server and client. I guess nginx configuration can help you to increase the max size for the requests from clients to your server deployed on ELB. Refer this [Increasing client_max_body_size in Nginx conf on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908426/increasing-client-max-body-size-in-nginx-conf-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk)