# Uploading large file to EB AWS service fail with error 400 bad request

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, file-upload, httprequest, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a mobile application that does uploading files to Elastic Bean AWS service, with Nodjs deployed API, the API then using skipperS3 do uploading the file to S3 Bucket, when I upload small files up to 60-100 MB the upload successfully done with no error, when I'm trying to upload larger file, I get

```
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>cloudflare</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I believe the error related to the server, not to the mobile application, any idea how to find the problem?

Please note I have more than instance running on Amazon with the load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

If your EB environment is running behind a load balancer, there's a default file size limit in NGINX that will reject large files.

This may be related: [increasing-client-max-body-size-in-nginx-conf-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908426/increasing-client-max-body-size-in-nginx-conf-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk)