# Increase client_max_body_size for Nginx on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Java 11

Tags: java, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, java-11

I have been trying to increase the **client_max_body_size** for the provided **Nginx** server in my **Java 11** Beanstalk deployment without success.

So far I have tried the [AWS Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html) method, [this](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/instance-configuration/change-nginx-max-body-size.config) approach in GitHub using a hook, as well as every posted solution I found in 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908426/increasing-client-max-body-size-in-nginx-conf-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk) StackOverflow question using different configurations in the .ebextenstions.

The errors I have faced are different depending on the approach I take, from the app not being deployed at all because of errors in the Nginx configuration to the app being deployed successfully but not taking the new file size limit into account. These are some of the bundle structures I have tried:

**Bundle 1**

```
myBundle.zip
--myApplication.jar
--Procfile
--.ebextensions
----nginx
------conf.d
--------proxy.conf
```

proxy.conf

```
client_max_body_size 50M;
```

**Bundle 2**

```
myBundle.zip
--myApplication.jar
--Procfile
--.ebextensions
----myconf.config
```

myconf.config

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      client_max_body_size 50M;

container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "sudo service nginx reload"
```

**Bundle 3**

```
myBundle.zip
--myApplication.jar
--Procfile
--.ebextensions
----myhookconfig.config
```

myhookconfig.config

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/12_add_nginx_configuration.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      /bin/echo "client_max_body_size 50M;" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf
      /sbin/service nginx reload
```

I presume this may have something to do with the EB Java 11 platform in specific. Have you guys accomplished to change this configuration in EB with Java 11? Thanks!

Comment: did u find solution ?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

Comment: Hi @vaquarkhan. I found the solution sometime later. I forgot to update my question, but the link you posted is actually the one I used. I'm posting now the working solution.

Answer (score 12):

Here is the solution that worked for me. My mistake is that I was using the configuration for the preceding Amazon Linux 2 platforms. As Vaquar Khan mentions, the link with the correct configuration is [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html). The section *Reverse Proxy Configuration* is what I was looking for.

Here is the configuration that increased the NGINX request max body size:

```
myBundle.zip
--myApplication.jar
--Procfile
--.platform
----nginx
------conf.d
--------myConf.conf
```

myConf.conf:

```
client_max_body_size 50M;
```

Comment: I think you can accept your answer as the accepted answer

Comment: Are you using Maven to build this zip, if so can you share the config?