# Aws Elastic beanstalk ebextensions not working when new instance is getting spinned

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

This is happening from last 1 week whenever my old elastic beanstalk instance getting terminated and AWS spinning up new instance its not picking eb extensions where I have mentioned.

```
files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
           client_max_body_size 20M;
```

due to which I am not able to upload any video from my APIs.

Comment: Can you define not working? Had there been any code change since the last instance change?

Comment: no Chris there is not any code change aws has just terminated the previous instance and launched the new one as we have auto scaling enabled

Comment: Not working - when i am trying to upload a video using my api its throwing ngnix 413 error

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/61943622/7532917
i have answered it there. Please check

Comment: Awesome worked for me @JijoCleetus can you please post the solution here also the question is specific to "new instance its not picking .ebextensions" and will help other users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using `.platform` folder.

```
.platform/
         nginx/
              conf.d/
                    proxy.conf
         00_myconf.config
```

Content of File 1 - proxy.conf (Inside `.platform/nginx/conf.d/` folder)

`client_max_body_size 50M;`

Content of File 2 - 00_myconf.config (Inside `.platform/` folder)

```
container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "service nginx reload"
```

Redeploy your app to elastic beanstalk and it will provide this configuration to all the new elastic beanstalk instances.

Comment: Just to add a little bit of context, this seems to be the way to do it on Amazon Linux 2, where as what OP had was a valid way to do it in Amazon Linux. Took me awhile to figure out this was the root cause.