# "413 Request Entity Too Large" errors occured while uploading file AWS. ( file size is 3MB)

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Using Post API to upload file to AWS storage and our API running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk( file size is 3 MB ). But when uploading file "413 Request Entity Too Large" errors occurred. I've done quite a bit of research and also refer following link but issue remain same. [Increasing client_max_body_size in Nginx conf on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908426/increasing-client-max-body-size-in-nginx-conf-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk)

Comment: Current answer for that link is appliable for Amazon Linux 1. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/61943622/7532917 whether it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The link you've provided works only for EB platform based on **Amazon Linux 1**.

Since you maybe using **Amazon Linux 2** you should be using different files for setting nginx. For AL2, the nginx settings should be in `.platform/nginx/conf.d/`, not in `.ebextentions` as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

Therefore, you could have the following `.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconfig.conf` with content:

```
client_max_body_size 5M;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , i have tried your solution but still end up with the same error 413 (Request Entity Too Large)

Comment: @sanketpatil Can you provide details of your setup? And please double check file names used.