# Stop automatic restart in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Elastic Beanstalk with Linux environment in many projects and noticed that the server is restarting automatically, and due to this, I have to re-run the command, for file permission, max upload size and Nginx related.

Is there any way to stop the automatic restart?

Comment: Restarting why? Any details?

Comment: Don't know, but can see in the EC2 launching time is updating and then I have to re-run the command and everything

Comment: Its not because of server restart, its basically because of the auto scaling mechanism in which new instances of your basic instance will be created and based on the usage it will delete instance with less usage. 
Please move your nginx related and file permission commands to .platform folder and upload. Please check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61943622/7532917

Comment: .platform folder will be considered during new instance creation and you will get all the configuration in any number of instances creating