# client intended to send too large body EB Nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, upload, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to increase the size of uploadable files to the server. However it seems there's a cap that prevents anything over 1MB of being uploaded.

I've read a lot of answers and none have worked for me.

I've done everything in this question
[Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908426/increasing-client-max-body-size-in-nginx-conf-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk/28313384#28313384)

I did everything here as well.
[AWS resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html)

Here's what I have as the full error

```
2021/01/15 05:08:35 [error] 24140#0: *150 client intended to send too large body: 2695262 bytes, client: [ip-address-removed], server: , request: "PATCH /user HTTP/1.1", host: "host.domain.com", referrer: "host.domain.com"
```

I've made a file in this directory (which is at the root of my source code)

```
.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/myconf.conf
```

In it I have

```
client_max_body_size 40M;
```

I know that EB is acknowledging it because if there's an error it won't deploy it.
Other than that I have no idea what to do

Does anybody know what might be the issue here?

Edit: backend is nodejs v12

Edit: Also tried this inside of a .conf file in .ebextensions

```
files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/myconf.conf":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
          client_max_body_size 20M;
```

Comment: What is your backend? It can affect the limit as well. For example php-fpm has this option in php.ini.

Comment: @anemyte backend is nodejs v12

Comment: Wait a second... You put that nginx config in your source code, not in /etc/nginx, is that right?

Comment: Yes, it's inside of a folder called .ebextensions in my root folder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update**:

Beanstalk on Amazon Linux 2 AMI has a little different path for NGINX config extensions:

```
.platform/nginx/conf.d
```

There you can place NGINX config extension files with `*.conf` extension, for example:

*.platform/nginx/conf.d/upload_size.conf:*

```
client_max_body_size 20M;
```

Documentation for this is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

**Original answer**:

Nginx normally does not read config from where is serves the content. By default all config nginx read is `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and this file includes other files from `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` with `*.conf` extension.

You need to place `client_max_body_size 40M;` there.

Comment: thanks for the help but this isn't working for me either. It looks like EB sets default files from ebextensions. says it here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html) 

so i added this ```files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/myconf.conf":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
          client_max_body_size 20M;``` and it's still not working

Comment: @TrevorWood Oh I missed it is beanstalk. Try the following: from your source root create a file `.platform/nginx/conf.d/upload_size.conf` and put there a single line `client_max_body_size 20M;`. It's from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

Comment: thanks so much man. you're a lifesaver. Been stuck on this all day. You might add your answer to the link I posted in my question. Seems to get a lot of hits

Comment: @TrevorWood glad to help and thanks for the feedback. I've updated the answer.

Comment: You are a saviour. AWS Beanstalk would have killed me otherwise

Comment: This was very helpful thanks !!!, changes from Amazon Linux 1 to 2 is not seamless