# How to solve 413 "413 Request Entity Too Large" on elasticbeanstalk Django project

Tags: python-3.x, django, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am getting this error while uploading file of size larzer then 1MB and i am not able to configure nginx for Django project(Python) how to default file uploading size.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increasing client\_max\_body\_size in Nginx conf on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908426/increasing-client-max-body-size-in-nginx-conf-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the value of `client_max_body_size`
have a look to this site
https://techies-world.com/nginx-error-413-request-entity-too-large/