# 413 entity too large, nginx nodejs on elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, http-status-code-413

Using AWS Elastic Beanstalk, node: 12.13.1.

I am making put/post requests with images bigger than 1mb, and edited config files different ways to accept 10m files.

No matter the solution I tried, the server keeps rejecting requests with the same 413 error message.

I've tried:

- Creating a config file in a platform folder
- adding the conf file in ebextensions folder,
- Every solution in this thread: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908426/increasing-client-max-body-size-in-nginx-conf-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaitp.png)
- Directly SSH into the nginx server, and modify the config file, save and exit; but once the server restarts, the edit would be gone, and 413 would pop out again on each request.

[image: config folders]

[image: config file 2]

[image: config file 3]

I would appreciate anyone with a working alternative.
Thank you

Comment: First. Please do not paste code as screenshots, but properly formatted code blocks. Second, why do you have two `conf` files in your nginx? What do they do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue,
Some files starting with "." are hidden and have to be brought up with command + shift + "." .
Once the platform file is visible in the folder, and uploaded, it will work and increase the limit.