# Why is AWS Elastic Beanstalk not passing the custom JWT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, next-auth

I have successfully deployed a Next.js with Next-Auth project on AWS EB. Everything looks fine. However, I can't get passed the sign in form.

Here's what the browser console shows:

`502 Bad Gateway: POST http://----.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/auth/callback/credentials? Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Here's what the EB logs show:

`upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: , request: "POST /api/auth/callback/credentials? HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://-----/api/auth/callback/credentials?", host: "----", referrer: "http://----.elasticbeanstalk.com/"`

I've also shoved some console logs in `[...nextauth].tsx` file to find the issue.

- The console logs show fine all through the Providers.Credentials.
- The console logs show fine all through the jwt callbacks.
- But the console logs never appear in the session callback.

So it dies somewhere between jwt and session callback.

Here's the config that I have under `.ebextensions/`

`.ebextensions/proxy_custom.config`:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy_custom.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      proxy_buffer_size   128k;
      proxy_buffers   4 256k;
      proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "sudo service nginx reload"
```

Comment: You may need to adjust your nginx settings to increase buffer size. Do you mind posting your current config from `.ebextensions` folder?

Comment: @PsyGik I've edited the post to include what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by a cookie being too large to set.

The `.ebextensions` was never being applied. This is due to the app being under [Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html#platforms-linux-extend.proxy). The configs need to go under `.platform` for Amazon Linux 2.

These are the lines that did it:

```
proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61943622/5374225) from another post helped narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated config (based on what I've used), you may want to try them individually to see which config works best for you.

```yaml
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy_custom.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
      fastcgi_buffers 16 32k;
      fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
      proxy_buffer_size   128k;
      proxy_buffers   4 256k;
      proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "sudo service nginx reload"
```

make sure to check what the actual header sizes of your requests are and adjust the sizes accordingly. `curl -s -w \%{size_header} -o /dev/null https://example.com` by replacing `example.com` with your service url and add request headers via `-H`, if needed. This will give you the header size in bytes.

> don't set those buffers too high and use calculations specific to your app. Arbitrarily high values won't do good to your RAM, because those buffers are used *per connection*.

Reference: https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/tuning-proxy_buffer_size-in-nginx

Comment: Thank you! The information was useful. Any apps that are under Amazon Linux 2 need to add the configs to the `.platform` folder instead of the `.ebextensions` folder.

Comment: Nice catch! Thank you for sharing